# iPhone updated to iOS 8 not allows debug in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, xcode5, ios8, xcode6

Can I debug my application without installing Xcode 6?

I do not want to introduce the iOS 8 features still... I just want to debug my device updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open up Xcode 6, plug in your iOS 8 device and wait until Xcode can see your device, then Quit Xcode 6 and open up Xcode 5, it should now see your device.

I have been using my iOS 8 beta device with Xcode 5 for some time with this method.

Answer (score 3):

XCode 5 does not support iOS 8 in any way. Just update to XCode 6. It doesn't take long, especially if you have speedy internet.